# Placing the first letter in a string to the end of the string

Tags: javascript, html, string

I'm trying to position the first letter of a string to the end of that string. Here is my code.

```js
document.getElementById("modify").addEventListener("click", switchLetter);
    
function switchLetter () {
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  input = input.split("");
}
```

```html
Type a String, And I will Modify it:<br />
<input type="text" id="input" />
<input type="text" id="output" /><br />

<button id="modify">Modify</button>
```

At this point input[0] will return the first letter of the string entered. I tried doing input[0].reverse(); But that doesn't seem to be correct.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `input.split("")` is unnecessary. You can do `input[0]` even if `input` is a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr). It takes 2 arguments, where the first one is your start position, and the second one the length.

```js
function switchLetter () {
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  document.getElementById("input").value = input.substr(1) + input.substr(0,1);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"><button onclick="switchLetter()">Switch!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a new string where the first letter is moved to the end you can do something like this:

```
input = input.substring(1) + input.substring(0,1)
```

`substring(1)` returns the entire string starting at index 1.  `substring(0,1)` returns the first letter.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: That's still too complicated. What about `input.substring(1) + input[0]`? In Javascript, strings are treated a lot like arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
// e.g "abcd" is the input
var str = "abcd"; // or the input value using getElement value
var start = str[0] // "a"
var end = str[str.length - 1] // "d"
var mid = str.substr(1, str.length - 2); // "bc"

var newStr = end + mid + start; // will be "dcba"
```